# How do I restore a plain text postgres .backup file

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I exported a postgres db from pgAdmin in a plain format because I wanted to search the whole db text. I then tried to restore the database back but it gives an error saying that the archive file is not valid archive file. How do I restore the db back if it can be restored?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

run:

```
psql -U your_user_name your_db_name < your_dump_file
```

Comment: I am on windows 7. Can I do this on windows 7?

Comment: it should, if *psql* frontend is included in the postgresql package. Try to fire up a terminal, then *cd* to postgresql bin directory and try to run *psql*

Comment: I tried it now. It didnt work. There is psql.bat file in the postgres bin directory. I am using postgres 8.3

Comment: what do you mean with 'it didnt work'? if there is psql.bat however, try with that, it should run psql. look here for help http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-admin/2006-12/msg00091.php

Comment: Sorry I meant there is no psql.bat file in the bin directory

Comment: sorry but pgadmin cannot restore plain text dumps afaik; so you have two options if you deleted your db and you only have that backup: 1 you depend on running psql frontend in terminal as above; 2 you open the plain text backup and select all/copy, then paste everything in a pgadmin query window and run

Comment: This works, only the first argument after `-U` needs to be your user name not the data base name. psql -U your_user_name your_db_name < your_dump_file