# How save psql `ERROR` output to the same file as the DDL commands?

Tags: postgresql, windows

I'm trying to restore a database from a text file. I'm following the answer on this question. [How do I restore a plain text postgres .backup file](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13585/how-do-i-restore-a-plain-text-postgres-backup-file)

But add: `> c:\result.txt`

```
psql.exe -U  sde sde < c:\backup\sde_04_06_2018.backup > c:\backup\result.txt
```

This seem to work but doesn't write the errors.

You get messages like this on the text file:

```
REVOKE
GRANT
SET
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
```

But on the command windows you see error like this:

```
ERROR:  constraint "sde_layer_stats_version_id_fkey" for relation sde_layer_stats" already exists
ERROR:  constraint "xml_columns_fk1" for relation "sde_xml_columns" already exists
ERROR:  constraint "xml_columns_fk2" for relation "sde_xml_columns" already exists
ERROR:  constraint "xml_indextags_fk1" for relation "sde_xml_index_tags" already exists
```

The idea is save the error on the text file so I can review and decide if are something I need to handle.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want help with how write the command line so I can save the output of the restore to a file.txt. So the create/insert/alter on the backup aren't relevant. And the image is just as reference, I also include the message as text just in case.

If you're asking how do you put the error to the "result file" too, you need to [redirect `STDERR` as well as `STDOUT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1420981/124486) or direct `STDERR` to `STDOUT` with `2>&1`

```
psql.exe -U  sde sde < c:\backup\sde_04_06_2018.backup > c:\backup\result.txt 2>&1
```

Internally you have three "standard" streams: input, output, and error.

- `input` you're directing that to `c:\backup\sde_04_06_2018.backup`
- `output` you're directing output to `c:\backup\result.txt`
- **You need to also redirect `error`.**

Comment: Thanks Evan. But I just got the same result as before.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza try that (moving `2>&1` to the end)

Comment: Perfect. Just for feedback. You answer direct to my comment instead of the question. Do you think my question wasn't clear enough?

Comment: Well, I didn't read properly at first -- so yea, it can always be cleaer. For instance, as it turned out -- it has nothing to do with PostgreSQL, or psql, or restoring a database. But, I can see how that would be **very** confusing to someone who doesn't understand the standard streams/sysadmin stuff.

Comment: It's ok, all good. Sometimes you don't have the information to make it clearer, I can't reasonably expect someone to ask "How do I redirect STDERR on Windows" if you don't yet know how the streams work. ;)